# Tip for using metal dome tactile switch

Tags: switches

[image: Metal domes to act as tactile switches]

I was thinking that I'd use some of these metal dome tactile switches for a project since they are cheap and low profile, but from where I am I can't seem to obtain the ones that can be soldered directly onto a PCB (or at least not cheap enough for a personal project), nor I can afford the cost of custom making a membrane to allow me to attach these metal dome switches onto to later lay over my PCB.

Do you guys have any tips to secure these little things onto my board? So far my only ideas is to just use transparent cellophane tape to just tape these over my PCB, will that bring any issues?

Comment: Maybe you could use four staple-shaped pieces of tinned copper wire to hold each of them down; at least it would last a few more presses than sticky tape.

Comment: Are you sure you can't solder them? If they're nickel-plated, they may just be difficult to solder--you need to use plenty of flux. But if they're stainless steel or something, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Hearth Nope, not even if the material allows it, mainly due to the fact that those for "legs" will snap up when you press the center down, if I solder them onto my board, the solder will break overtime and be really unreliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent duct tape works quite well, and is tougher than just sellotape. I've used in the past, and as long as it doesn't get too hot (which softens the glue) no problem.